# OROCRM "Error occured while loading template."

Tags: php, symfony, apache2, orocrm

We are using OROCRM with Apache2 on our server. I can create new email template successfully. But when I try use it in Lead > More Actions > Send Email section, it alerts me "Error occured while loading template."

I have looked the error.log file. Nothing logged. I give 777 to all path. No problem about permissions. How can I watch the problem? Is there a any OROCRM error log file etc?

Answer (score 0):

Check app/log/prod.log if you run in prod mode.

Comment: Thanks. But there is nothing about my problem. All logs are start with `security.DEBUG`

Comment: try to use app_dev.php endpoint (dev environment) and check app/log/dev.log as well as browser console (probably response body will contain some error)

Comment: When using app_dev.php, everything works well! When using app.php, chrome console


* GET http://url/crm-application/web/api/rest/latest/emailtemplates/list/OroCRM_Bundle_SalesBundle_Entity_Lead 404 (Not Found)
* GET http://url/crm-application/web/api/rest/latest/emailtemplates/compiled/16/3 404 (Not Found)